# Database "Migration" for Plugins?

Tags: php, plugin-development, sql

I'm creating a plugin for WordPress.  This plugin will need to save data to the database.  In other programming frameworks I've worked with, there are systems called "database migrations".  These migrations are

- SQL `ALTER TABLE` or `CREATE TABLE` statements/scripts
- Sometimes abstracted into the programming language of the framework
- Written and stored in a common way such that a user of my plugin/extension/etc can say "run the migrations" and the database will be update, per my instructions

  - And sometimes includes features that allow you to "rollback" those changes

An example migration system [is Laravel's](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations).

Does WordPress have a system that's similar to migrations?  If not, is there a canonical way (via a particular hook, plugin registration, etc) to package up the new database tables and/or changes to existing WordPress tables my plugin will need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Surprisingly not. Instead, you need to use the following function which is run whenever the plugin is activated.

```
define( 'YOUR_PLUGIN_VERSION', '1.0.0' );

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'your_plugin_activation_function' );

function your_plugin_activation_function() {
  // Do activation tasks here.
  your_install_function();
  your_upgrade_migration_function();
}
```

Run your install script.

```
function your_install_function() {

  // Set the current version of the plugin in the db.
  update_option( 'your_plugin_version', YOUR_PLUGIN_VERSION );
}
```

Then for each new version, you do a compare which basically performs your database migrations, etc.

```
function your_upgrade_migration_function() {

  // Using a version prior to 1.1.1
  if ( version_compare( YOUR_PLUGIN_VERSION, '1.1.1', '<' ) ) {
    // Do upgrade things unique for this version.
  }

  // Using a version prior to 1.2.0
  if ( version_compare( YOUR_PLUGIN_VERSION, '1.2.0', '<' ) ) {
    // Do upgrade things unique for this version.
  }
}
```

Comment: Useful, thank you.  What about something like dbDelta -- is that OK to trust/use in place for version compares? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/dbdelta/

Comment: @AlanStorm Yes - If you're creating/modifying a db table, dbDelta is what you need. https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins#Creating_or_Updating_the_Table Ideally though, you leverage the existing WordPress schema and caching layer by storing any plugin data in the wp_options table.

Comment: +1'd for your answer, thank you. I'm leaving this open for a bit -- still hoping for something more complete (this answer missed dbDelta, curious if there's other functions/systems to help with migration like tasks)